# How to run a command in Developer command prompt 2019 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to do build in Developer Command Prompt of VS 2019 using Python script.

Here is piece of code i'm using:

import os
os.system('start /wait C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe  "msbuild C:/Users/Desktop/Project/Project.sln"')
os.system("pause")

But it is not working.Developer command prompt is appearing for just 1sec and disappearing .

When i took variable to check if command was succesful or not ,it is giving variable result as zero,which means command is successful but i'm not able to see it in Developer command prompt.

result= os.system('start /wait C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /k ipconfig')
print (result)

Whereas when i'm trying the same command in windows command prompt it's working fine.

Comment: What is the error message of your issue?

Comment: error is not there ,developer command prompt is popping up for 1sec and disappearing again.So i'm not sure if whole build is getting done or not.

Answer (score 0):

> How to run a command in Developer command prompt 2019 using Python

`Developer command prompt 2019` is a tool which is integrated into VS2019 IDE and provides environment parameters for various development modules.

**However**, the `CMD.exe` does not have these environment variables for these, so you cannot just use `CMD.exe` directly. Sorry that I am not familiar with python code and script. I suggest you could configure `Developer command prompt 2019` into System environment variable `PATH`and then call `cmd.exe` which integrates the related variables to build your projects without any errors.

**Suggestion**

**First**, if you build your project on another new agent, you should install one of tool from **step 1**.

**1)** If you install VS2019 IDE in your local agent,please make sure that your local agent has VS2019 IDE and install the related workload about your project type.

**Besides**, if you install `Build Tool for VS2019`, please also install the related workload.

**2)** set the below path under System environment variable **PATH**

**VS2019 IDE**:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

**Build Tool for VS2019**:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

**3)** Then you can call your python script as you described to build your projects.

Any feedback and concern will be expected.

Comment: i have set up the path but still same issue is happening.DEveloper command prompt is appearing for 1sec and then disappearing again.

Comment: Actually, it is the normal behavior that python script runs develop command prompt but its result will not return back. The message is provided by Developer command prompt, so it is not the job of python script. So you should write some code to extract its information and it is a bit complex. Since you run it in developer command prompt successfully, so when you use python script, it will also work.

Comment: To prove it, you can try this: delete the bin,obj folder under `Project` and then run this python script and if you find the execute program and output file in the generated bin folder, it  means that it works very well.

Comment: hi That bin and obj will not generate because build is taking almost 6minutes to complete but developer command prompt is popping up for 1 sec only .Do you have any idea ,how can i open Developer command prompt for a longer time to complete my build